# How to create collections of a specific enum variant?

Tags: vector, rust, enums, enumeration

I would like to create a vector of a specific variant of an enum in Rust. For example:

```
enum EnumExample {
    VariantExample,
}

fn main() {
    let singleEnum = EnumExample::VariantExample;
    let vectorOfEnums = Vec::<EnumExample>::new();
    let vectorOfEnumVariants = Vec::<EnumExample::VariantExample>::new();
}
```

But for `vectorOfEnumVariants`, I get the error `error[E0573]: expected type, found variant 'EnumExample::VariantExample'`. Is there a way to do this? Is there something else I should be doing instead?

Comment: I don't think you can constrain to an specific variant of an enum. It actually do not make sense.

Comment: Note: what you want was proposed as a feature, but is currently postponed: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593

Comment: An enum is a type. An enum variant is a specific value. What you are asking for is a bit like "I don't want a vector of `i32`. I want a vector of only fours." Of course there is the difference that enum variants can have associated data of a specific type. You can have a vector of the data type associated with the variant, but that's not a vector of the enum variant, but a vector of some other type.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way of constraining to an `enum` variant. But you can use inner types for your enums and create a `Vec` of those, then implement `From` so you can transform those into the enum variants whenever you need:

```rust
struct Variant;

enum EnumExample {
    VariantExample(Variant),
}

impl From<Variant> for EnumExample {
    fn from(v: Variant) -> Self {
        Self::VariantExample(v)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let singleEnum = EnumExample::VariantExample;
    let vectorOfEnums = Vec::<EnumExample>::new();
    let vectorOfVariants = Vec::<Variant>::new();
    let vectorOfEnumVariants: Vec<EnumExample> =
        vectorOfVariants.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc18c7ca77178f8456018130c50f1f52)

Comment: Fully agree with this. I think the basic problem is that `enum` is the wrong type for the problem. It should be a `struct` instead. It could be wrapped inside an `enum` afterwards, but if you want to put it in a vector, it should be its own type.

Comment: This is the most idiomatic solution. There is even precedence for it [in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html).